# How to add internal bookmarks to Outlook Email via HTML?

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin

I am creating an HTML email, and would like to add a table of contents which shows hyperlinks to items in the email. My currently workflow is simply generating the complete HTML file and then displaying that HTML file within the HTMLBody of an Outlook mail item.

When I open the HTML page in a browser, it works fine. But when I set the Outlook mail HTMLBody equal to that text, the bookmarks no longer work.

The bookmark hyperlinks look akin to:
`<a href = "#item" ...>Blah<\a>`

Where an item in the HTML has the `name` and `id` attributes equal to `"item"`

How do I get the bookmarks to work?

Answer (score 0):

Please set the email type to html..  something like this..

*// Set the format of the mail message body as HTML*

mMailMessage.IsBodyHtml = **IsBodyHtml;**

Answer (score 0):

With Outlook 2010, it helped me, when i use `<a name="item"></a>` as a bookmark. i.e. exactly "A" item.